# creating a file with current date as file name and checking for the file's existence with python

Tags: python, file, readfile, os.path

I'm trying something like this.

```
data = "test data" + '\n'

now = datetime.now() 

now = str(now)

f1 = str((now).split(" ") [0])

f2 = "macaddress"

file_name = f1 + '_' + f2

fout = open(file_name,'a+')

while 1:
   fout.write("data")
```

File has been created successfully with current date as file name and data has been written onto the file. But the problem I'm getting is If I check for the existence of the file, it is showing that the file doesn't exists, even though the file exists.

I tried to check the existence using `if(os.path.isfile(file_name)):`

Comment: Why do you've a single quote before `file_name`? That's a syntax error.

Comment: Can't tell if OP forgot to include the quote at the end of `file_name`, or accidentally put it on the beginning (in transcribing to post). If it's quoted that'd certainly be the answer

Comment: Can you update the question with the entire code upto the point where you check the existence of the file?

Comment: Ashwini I have removed the quote before

Comment: @RLN very next is ambiguous here: You mean inside the while loop or after it?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Not inside the while loop. I meant the very next line and not in range of while indent.-RLN

Comment: @RLN Then your code will never reach that next line, as your `while` loop creates an infinite loop.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Yeah you are right. But even if i remove the while loop and place my existence check in the very next line, it doesn't works.

Comment: @RLN It works for me, post the exact code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Are you trying this thing in windows environment?

Comment: @RLN Tested on both Ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split datetime into a string. It would be easier to use a f-string (Make sure you format it). For an example, I'll create a text file with the date as the name.

```
import datetime
import os

filestream = "yourpathhere"
docdate = f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')}"

filetype = ".txt"

path = f"{filestream}{docdate}{filetype}"

with open(path, "w") as file:
    mymessage = f"Hello, I am a text file!"

    # Write to the newly created file
    file.write(mymessage)
    
    # Close the opened file #
    file.close()
```

You can use the `isfile()` method to check if the file is there.

```
if (os.path.isfile(path)):
    print("The file:", path, "has already been created")
```